# Recyclerview support library isn't working in buildtoolversion 28.0.3 with android jetpack

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-jetpack

I have buildToolVersion '28.0.3', which is the most most recent, and i have

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.3'
```

in my build gradle file, and in an cloned from google codelabs, where recyclerview is used, it doesn't show import option, i can't use recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use buildToolVersion 28.0.0, added these lines in build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

and now in the classes it uses, 
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.
and it works now.